# Why are two tabloids of the same shape column permutations of each other?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\{T_1\}$ and $\{T_2\}$ be two tabloids of the same shape. My professor today said in class that this implies $\{T_2\}=\pi\{T_1\}$ for some $\pi\in C_{T_1}$.

What does this mean? Does $\pi$ act on the tableau $T_1$, or the tabloid $\{T_1\}$?

Comment: The subgroup $C(T_1)\leq S_n$ consists of permutations fixing columns of $T_1$ setwise. In defining this, we already have some notion of how $S_n$ acts (transitively) on elements of $\{T_1\}$. I wonder if you misheard something.

Comment: A permutation $\pi \in S_n$ acts both on the set of tableaux of a given shape $\lambda \vdash n$, and on the set of tabloids of this shape. (It acts on tableaux by interchanging entries, i.e., if we regard a tableau as a map from the shape to $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, then it acts by post-composing this map with $\pi$. It is easy to see that this action does project to an action on tabloids, i.e., if two tableaux $T_1$ and $T_2$ are row-equivalent, then so are $\pi T_1$ and $\pi T_2$.)

Comment: Your professor's claim can be rewritten (less ambiguously) as follows: If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are two tableaux of a given shape $\lambda \vdash n$ (each filled with the entries $1, 2, \ldots, n$, each appearing exactly once), then there exist two mutually column-equivalent tableaux $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ such that $Q_1$ is row-equivalent to $T_1$, and such that $Q_2$ is row-equivalent to $T_2$.

Comment: Actually, this claim is false, as you can see by setting $n = 5$, $\lambda = \left(3,1,1\right)$, $T_1 = \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{array}$ and $T_2 = \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{array}$. But maybe it holds for rectangular $\lambda$.

Comment: Actually, I think it fails for rectangular $\lambda$, too: try transforming a tableau $T_1$ into its transpose for $\lambda = \left(2,2\right)$.